# Testing abstract class with JPA repository dependency

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, powermock

I have an abstract class which I would like to unit test.

```
public abstract class Processor {

    private final MyRepo repo;

    protected Processor (final MyRepo repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public abstract MyResponse process(final Request req, final String id);

    protected void saveRequest(final Request req, final String id) {

        final Entity entity = Entity.builder()                
                .status(SUCCESS.name())
                .build();

        Entity entity = repo.save(entity);
        LOG.debug("Entity Saved {}", entity);
    }

    protected boolean checkDupe(final Request req) {
        return repo.check(request.getname(), LocalDate.parse(request.getDate()));
    }   
}
```

I have the following Unit Test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class ProcessorAbstractClassTest{

    @Mock
    private MyRepo repo;

    @Test
    public void shouldSaveRequest() {

        Processor processor = Mockito.mock(
                Processor.class,
                Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);


        MyRequest req = new MyRequest ("blah blah");

        Entity entity = Entity.builder().build();

        processor.saveRequest(req, "123");

       //check object passed into save but not save
    }

}
```

I would like to test there has been interaction with `save()` and validate the object Entity that is passed into it. How can I achieve this given that this is an abstract class and the concrete impl classes are providing the dependencies with `super(repo)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `verify(repo).save(isA(Entity.class));`

Answer (score 0):

Since I had concrete classes which extends Processor class, I used them to test the super class methods.

For example:

```
@Test
public void givenNonAbstractMethod_whenConcreteImpl_testCorrectBehaviour() {
    MyConcreteProcessor proc = new MyConcreteProcessor ();
    String actual = proc.saveRequest(new MyRequest());
 
    assertEquals("TEST", actual);
}
```